# What are the commands for creating a new Google Document via the Google Docs API Python Client Library?

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I would like to create a new Google Document from the command line using the Google Docs API Python Client Library (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client).

What are the commands for creating a new document?

Comment: I cannot understand about `commands` of `What are the commands for creating a new document?`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 0):

- For creating a new document with Google Docs API use [Method: documents.create](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create)
- The implementation of this method in Python is featured in the [Google Docs API PyDoc documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/docs/v1/python/latest/index.html)

**Sample:**

```py
body = {
    'title': 'myTitle'
}
doc = service.documents().create(body=body).execute()
```